# Count how many 1 in integer's binary

Tags: c, count, binary

[image]
Sample Input

```
2
2
5
```

Sample Output

```
0 1 1
0 1 1 2 1 2
```

---

### I already knew how to transfer an integer to its binary and count how many 1 in its binary.
But my code only can input one integer each time. I want it to input many numbers, like the sample input and sample output. To make question more easy to understand, so I drew a picture. Thank you!!

Thanks all of you!! But I need some time to understand those code and my English is pretty basic, so I couldn't reply you guys soon. But I will understand and reply you as soon as possible!!thank you :D

---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,cnt=0,m;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n>0){
        m=n%2;
        if(m==1){
            cnt++;
        }
        n/=2;
    }
    printf("%d",cnt);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Toma, add as the tag the language that you are using

Comment: please add `C` language tag to it

Comment: Oh, thank you all so much!!

Comment: You should check the return value of `scanf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practice, the process can be simplified and accelerated by noticing that if we know the result for `i < 2^p`, then, for all values in `[2^p, 2^(p+1)-1]`, we have

```
count(j) = 1 + count(j-2^p)
```

This method is useful here as we have to provide the result for all values less or equal to `n`.

Moreover, in order to avoid performing the same calculation at different times, we first calculate the maximum `n` value, and perform the calculation for this maximum value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int t;
    int check = scanf("%d", &t);
    if (check != 1) return 1;
    int nn[t];
    for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
        int check = scanf("%d", &nn[i]);
        if (check != 1) return 1;
    }
    int nmax = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
        if (nn[i] > nmax) nmax = nn[i];
    }
    int count[nmax+1];
    count[0] = 0;
    count[1] = 1;
    int pow2 = 1;
    do {
        pow2 *= 2;
        for (int j = pow2; (j < 2*pow2) && (j <= nmax); j++) {
            count[j] = 1 + count[j-pow2];
        }
    } while (pow2 <= nmax+1);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= nn[i]; ++j) {
            printf ("%d ", count[j]);
        }
        printf ("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let the number of measured values be `t`. Now if you want to take `t` number of integers as input, you have to run a loop `t` times and perform necessary tasks (like taking value of n, calculating `cnt` etc) inside that loop. Check the following code snippet:

```c
int main()
{
    int n,cnt=0,m;
    int numberOfMeasuredValues;
    scanf("%d", &numberOfMeasuredValues);
    while(numberOfMeasuredValues > 0){
        cnt = 0;
        scanf("%d",&n);
        // perform necessary calculations
        printf("%d\n",cnt);
        numberOfMeasuredValues--;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the code `numberOfMeasuredValues` is the `t` I've used in the explanation.

Comment: @Toma, this answer addresses the issue regarding taking multiple integers as input. However, from what I'm observing, the code you posted will not produce the output in required format. For n=2, it should produce `0 1 1`. But the provided snippet will produce `1` only.

Comment: Please check the return value of `scanf`

Comment: @ClaudioDeLise, to keep the code simple I think it is okay to ignore the return value of `scanf()` in this case.It is because we can safely assume that the test file will contain the number of test samples at the beginning. In other words, if there is no sample, its value will be 0 and so the loop will not be executed.

Comment: I agree but it should still be noted that this type of function needs to be checked. If you get used to doing it with easy codes, you never go wrong with more difficult codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-allocate number of cases and work on them with outer and inner loops. I've added the code with comments below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int cases;      // Number of cases
    scanf("%d", &cases);

    int* nums = malloc(cases * sizeof *nums);   // Allocate enough space.

    /* Take the inputs. */
    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", (nums + i));
    }

    int cnt = 0;    // Counter for number of 1s.

    // Outer loop for going through cases.
    for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++)
    {
        // Inner loop for couting towards inputted number.
        for (int j = 0; j < *(nums + i) + 1; j++)
        {
            /* 
            *  You can Implement this part by yourself if you wish.
            */
            for (int k = 0; k < 32; k++)
            {
                if ((j >> (31 - k)) & 0x01) cnt++;  // Increment counter if digit is 1.
            }
            printf("%d ", cnt);
            cnt = 0;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Always check return value of `scanf`

Comment: `void main(void) { /* ... */ }` isn't a correct way to define the `main` function. Also, in `C`, the cast operator in `(int*)malloc` is useless. The idiomatic way to allocate space using the `malloc` is `nums = malloc(cases * sizeof *nums);`

Comment: `scanf("%d", (nums + 1))` should be wrong. Probably `scanf("%d", &nums[i])` or an equivalent form is intended.

Comment: Yes, `scanf("%d", (nums + 1))` was a bad edit and i fixed it now. Thanks for pointing it out. I will check out your other suggestions.

Answer (score -3):

Here's the following code to your problem

```py
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int tcs;
    cin >> tcs;
    while (tcs--) {
        int n;
        cin >> n;
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= n ; i++) {
            cout << __builtin_popcount(i) << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! you wrote this code so quick!! But I haven't learned c++ so I couldn't understand very well. I will try to understand your code, thank you again!!(❁´ω`❁)*✲ﾟ*